# Iframe and firefox problems

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, rich-text-editor

I am designing a simple Rich Text Editor using HTML/Javascript. It uses iframe. While it is working great in IE6 (and possibly newer IE versions), it is broken in FireFox. The iframe cannot be edited or used in any way.

**The HTML `<body>`**

```
<input type="button" id="bold" class="Button" value="B" onClick="fontEdit('bold');">
<input type="button" id="italic" class="Button" value="I" onClick="fontEdit('italic');">
<input type="button" id="underline" class="Button" value="U" onClick="fontEdit('underline');">
<hr>
<iframe id="TextEditor" class="TextEditor"></iframe>
```

**The Javascript (for IE)**

```
TextEditor.document.designMode="on";
TextEditor.document.open();
TextEditor.document.write('<head><style type="text/css">body{ font-family:arial; font-size:13px; }</style> </head>');
TextEditor.document.close();
TextEditor.focus();
```

*The above script makes iframe editable in IE. Fails to do so in FF. So I changed a few things for FF version-*

**The Javascript (for FF)**

```
id("TextEditor").contentWindow.designMode="on";
id("TextEditor").contentWindow.open(); //this line is responsible for pop-ups
id("TextEditor").contentWindow.write('<head><style type="text/css">body{ font-family:arial; font-size:13px; }</style> </head>'); //this line throws error: id("TextEditor").contentWindow.write is not a function at the FF debug console.
id("TextEditor").contentWindow.close();
id("TextEditor").focus();
```

*This section of code makes FF provoke an pop-up alert with a blank page as a target. It's still broken. What now follows are general functions for things like `id()` and `fontEdit()`-*

```
function fontEdit(x,y){
  TextEditor.document.execCommand(x,"",y);
  TextEditor.focus();
}

function id(id){
  return document.getElementById(id);
}

function tag(tag){
  return document.getElementsByTagName(tag);
}
```

I'm sure FF doesn't handle iframe this way. So how do I get iframe to be used as a Rich Text Editor and without showing pop-ups. Please try your best to avoid jQuery since I'm not that good in it yet. Which is why the custom functions like `id()` and `tag()` exists.

And, I'm aware that there are other freely available Text Editors for *me* to download and use so please do not suggest me any such solutions and do not ask me *why* I must re-invent the wheel. Only answer if you know where I am going wrong and if you can actually *help* me fix the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FF provoke an pop-up alert with a blank page as a target because you are calling the function `window.open`, instead you shoud call `document.open`.

`window.open`: opens a new browser window.

`document.open`: It opens an output stream to collect the output from any `document.write()` or `document.writeln()` methods. Once all the writes are performed, the `document.close()` method causes any output written to the output stream to be displayed.
**Note**: If a document already exists in the target, it will be cleared.

See [The open() method](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/elements.html#dom-document-open)

This should works for you:

```
id("TextEditor").contentWindow.document.designMode="on";
id("TextEditor").contentWindow.document.open(); //this line is responsible for pop-ups
id("TextEditor").contentWindow.document.write('<head><style type="text/css">body{ font-family:arial; font-size:13px; }</style> </head>'); //this line throws error: id("TextEditor").contentWindow.write is not a function at the FF debug console.
id("TextEditor").contentWindow.document.close();
```

Comment: @Samik, as an extra part (not worthy of an answer in itself, especially as this answer is correct), it would also be more efficient to set `id("TextEditor").contentWindow.document` into a variable - rather than have to find the object over and over again

Comment: @m.abbas - as I was writing the above comment, you removed the explanation from your answer. I would suggest that you put it back (if possible) as it's always good for people who find this question/answer in the future to understand exactly **why** your answer works.

Comment: @freefaller you are right but i was looking for a better explanation.

Comment: @freefaller Thanks for your tip. I'll surely keep that in mind when I update my codes.